# Animation between different instances of one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to add animation to my android app, and knew a lot about transition animation between activities, and about fragments. So I have **MainActivity** with some view (image), and **SecondActivity** which is empty itself, but contains fragments, which then needs to be used to display some detail information about this image. I've read about `postponeentertransition()` and it worked. But the problem is, that this fragment in second activity have links(or transitions) to the same kind of fragment.

Let's say in main activity I have set of images of cars, then I click one, second activity is starting and waiting for fragment loading, and then shows animation. And then, in this fragment I have "similar cars" recycler, and choose one of them, and wants, to show its details the same way, but with adding this fragment to the backstack (not replacing). So the problem is that transition name of the view in main activity and big image of fragment are the same (which is obvious), and transition name in fragment's recycler and big image of the next fragment have to be the same too(otherwise app doesn't know how to make the animation). On the other side, fragment (which was added) has to be the same class, but its different instance.

I just want to set up animation without crashing the existing architecture.:) If you have any solutions or advices how to make animation between different instances of one fragment, please help.)

Comment: Add code snippet you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setCustomAnimations` on the Fragment transaction (see below). It doesn't matter if the instances are from the same class.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// To animate the fragment
// NOTE: Must be before replace/add otherwise it doesn't work
transaction
   .setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, popEnter, popExit)
   .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, null)
   .commit();
```